# Deleting Row above cell containing file name

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet where a file name is somewhere in column "A." I am trying to write code to find that location and delete all the rows above the row in which the file name is found. But something is wrong in my code & error `run time error "91"
object variable or with block variable not set` is appearing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub abcd()

Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range

rowCount = 20
sourceCol = 1
lastRow = 22
strSearch = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

Set oSht = Sheets(1)
Set aCell = oSht.Range("1:" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Rows(1 & ":" & aCell.Row - 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So what happens when the file name is found in row number one. How will you delete row 0? Most likely that's your issue.

Comment: @Nafis this part of the range setting `Set aCell = oSht.Range("1:" & lastRow)` cant be used like this. If you are using Range with "" you need to have setting like "A5", etc... If you want to have numbers, you need to use `Range(Cells(Row, Col), Cells(Row, Col))`

Comment: thanks for quick response, but I have already tired this way also.
even if I write  Range("A5:A10") OR rows(1:5)  same problem occurs

And in my format name will never found in row 1, so we need not to worry for this.

Comment: At which line the run time error appears?

Comment: in this line of code Rows(1 & ":" & aCell.Row - 1).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: I just copied your code and it works fine for me so maybe it is because of some piece of code you did not share here

Comment: I shared complete code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, my original code only deleted the one line above. Below is the corrected code. I think your problem is `Rows` is about the `ActiveSheet`, you should qualify that you want to work with `oSht`.

You could replace the `If` block by :

```
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
   oSht.Rows(1 & ":" & aCell.Row - 1).Delete
End If
```

Note that `EntireRows` is unnecessary, `Rows` already returns entire rows.

Comment: This will only delete one row. Nafis wants to delete all of the above rows